# How to link external storage (BackBlaze) and MySQL using Python (updated)

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, backblaze

Quick intro to the modules:
app.py - runs basic flask app, which imports file to MySQL database using SQLAlchemy.
storage.py - has a connection to BackBlaze, which picks up a file from static folder and sends it for storage, storage link gets generated from BackBlaze.

I'm trying to amend the code so, once I upload the file to flask via app.py, file link is saved in MySQL and actual file is sent to BackBlaze. Can you please assist to link two modules?

app.py

```
from io import BytesIO
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from storage import backblazeload

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret key'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:password@localhost/fof'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)


class Trades(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.String(50))
    data = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
    link = db.Column(db.String(200))


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        upload = Trades(filename=file.filename, data=file.read())
        db.session.add(upload)
        db.session.commit()

        # Generate the BackBlaze link and save it to the database
        link = backblazeload(file)
        upload.link = link
        db.session.commit()

        return f'Uploaded: {file.filename}'
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/download/<upload_id>')
def download(upload_id):
    upload = Trades.query.filter_by(id=upload_id).first()
    return send_file(upload.data, attachment_filename=upload.filename, as_attachment=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

storage.py

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from b2sdk.v2 import InMemoryAccountInfo, B2Api
from io import BytesIO


def backblazeload(file):
    load_dotenv()

    info = InMemoryAccountInfo()  # store credentials, tokens and cache in memory
    b2_api = B2Api(info)

    application_key_id = "app_id"
    application_key = "app_key"
    b2_api.authorize_account("production", application_key_id, application_key)

    bucket = b2_api.get_bucket_by_name("pickabucketname")

    file_data = BytesIO(file.read())
    b2_file_name = file.filename
    file_info = {'how': 'good-file'}

    uploaded_file_info = bucket.upload_bytes(
        file_data,
        file_name=b2_file_name,
        file_infos=file_info
    )

    uploaded_file_id = uploaded_file_info['fileId']

    print(b2_api.get_download_url_for_fileid(uploaded_file_id))
```

I'm getting below error now:

TypeError: object of type '_io.BytesIO' has no len()

Comment: `TypeError: object of type '_io.BytesIO' has no len()` Sounds like `upload_bytes()` expects `file_data` to be of type `bytes` rather than `BytesIO`. Have you tried replacing `file_data = BytesIO(file.read())` with `file_data = file.read()`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to link external storage (BackBlaze) and MySQL using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75677998/how-to-link-external-storage-backblaze-and-mysql-using-python)

Comment: It's not a good idea to just repost your question.

Comment: You're correct, @NickODell. The clue is in the name, and docs: https://b2-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/bucket.html#b2sdk.v2.Bucket.upload_bytes

Comment: Thanks Nick. After the update with file_data = file.read() , next error comes up as: TypeError: 'FileVersion' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Thanks Metadaddy. I'm trying to limit myself working with flask, mysql, sqlalchemy as this is all new to me. I've checked your project that you suggested, but that has django and other more complex concepts. I've reposted the this question as the other got closed by the system, will try to avoid these instances in the future.

Comment: Thanks Сергей Кох. What other information do you need? I had instances where I'm told that I'm giving too little info. In this instance, you can copy the above code, change passwords, install BackBlaze and MySQL and be able to run this code.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues in `storage.py` are:

- As mentioned in the commends, you're passing a `BytesIO` to `bucket.upload_bytes()`, when it just wants the bytes
- You're treating the [`FileVersion`](https://b2-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/data_classes.html#b2sdk.v2.FileVersion) object returned by `bucket.upload_bytes()` as if it were a dict, causing the `'FileVersion' object is not subscriptable` error.

This should work for you:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from b2sdk.v2 import InMemoryAccountInfo, B2Api
from io import BytesIO


def backblazeload(file):
    load_dotenv()

    info = InMemoryAccountInfo()  # store credentials, tokens and cache in memory
    b2_api = B2Api(info)

    application_key_id = "app_id"
    application_key = "app_key"
    b2_api.authorize_account("production", application_key_id, application_key)

    bucket = b2_api.get_bucket_by_name("pickabucketname")

    file_data = file.read()
    b2_file_name = file.filename
    file_info = {'how': 'good-file'}

    uploaded_file_info = bucket.upload_bytes(
        file_data,
        file_name=b2_file_name,
        file_infos=file_info
    )

    uploaded_file_id = uploaded_file_info.id_

    print(b2_api.get_download_url_for_fileid(uploaded_file_id))
```